# Display file description in view using Download Count

Tags: views, files

I have created a view to display my most download files on the site and allow users to download them, to do this I am using the [download_file](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file) and [download_count](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_count) modules.

The view should display a list of the most download attachment files on the site, I need to display the file name, a download link and then the file description.

When I try to insert the file description into the view I start running into problems, I am doing this by adding the field_attachments field (which is the field inside of my content type that the files are entered into).

[image: Most popular files view]

When I add field_attachments all of the files associated with a files related node are displayed in the result, instead of what I expect which is just the single description for that file per row. This is probably an issue with relationships, does anyone know of a way to solve this?

[image: view results]

Comment: Sorry for posting the response a bit late, I had found the solution myself a while ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, I had to add another relationship for the fields file id "field_attachments:fid" and then applied that relationship to all of the other fields.

Then I changed the aggregation settings for the attachment description field to group by 'fid' with 'display' and 'description' as additional grouping columns.

Now my view output only displays the matching description of the file in that row.